# How to evaluate this integral$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{\omega^\alpha e^{i\omega t}}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^{2}+4(\zeta\omega_0\omega)^2}\,d\omega$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate the following integral?
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{\omega^\alpha e^{i\omega t}}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^{2}+4(\zeta\omega_0\omega)^2}\,d\omega$$

where $\alpha>0,t>0,\zeta>0,\omega_0>0$.

When $\alpha=0$, I can figure it out by Residue theorem. However, I do not have any idea how to calculate this integral when $\alpha>0$. Does this integral have an analytic solution?

Comment: What are your own thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: It seems an inverse Fourier transform problem.

Comment: I tried to calculate this integral by Residue theorem,but failed,could it be possible for you to offer some ideas? @JoonasIlmavirta

Comment: Partial fractions?

Answer (score 0):

Where it converges it seems to equal
$$
I(\alpha,t,\zeta,\omega_0)=\frac{\pi\exp\left(\frac{i\alpha\pi}{2}-\frac{t\omega_0}{\sqrt{4\omega_0^2z^2-1}}\right)\omega_0^{a-1}}{(4\omega_0^2\zeta^2-1)^{\frac{a+1}{2}}}
$$
but this only seems to hold for $\alpha<2$ (and potentially some other restrictions $4 \omega_0^2\zeta^2>1$ I think). This is purely by CAS, I'm just cleaning up old unanswered questions.